# export table from one firebird database to another

Tags: python-3.x, fdb

I need to export firebird database from one server to another.

like:

"IMPORT * FROM 1DB TO 2DB"

or something like that

im using python 3.11 and FDB lib

Answer (score 0):

Export data from the first table/database and import it into the second table/database like this:

```
fbexport -S -V mytable -D database1.gdb -H server1 -U username -P password -F mytable.fbx
fbexport -I -V mytable -D database2.gdb -H server2 -U username -P password -F mytable.fbx -R
```

Comment: how it looks like in code?